# Extra (diode?) protection for H-bridge to prevent damage - how?

Tags: h-bridge, schottky, back-emf

I am trying to use a IMS-1 H-Bridge with a 24V/20A psu and a motor 24V/20A.
I already burned one of these H-bridges in one direction and I assume that was caused by a back EMF.

Specs of the H-bridge are:

```
Rated voltage: 5V-24V
Maximum voltage: 5V-30V
When R1 position meets with a short circuit, VCC and B + shorted. VCC output voltage is the same with input voltage of the drive.
When R1 position open, VCC and B + disconnected. VCC input voltage 3-12V..
Current Rating: 20A
Peak Current: 59A
Switching frequency: 1K to 200kHz
```

So this thing already got some sort of protection but probably not enough. what circuit can I add between H-bridge and motor to get extra protection?
I want to make sure not more than 59A / 30V come back to it, better far below that. 
I read a lot about circuits for this but all describe the circuit inside the H-bridge.

I am soldering for 30 years or more but my knowledge is like limited W/V=A :-/

Comment: Have you read about flyback diodes? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode

Comment: Show your current circuit please.

Comment: Yes I read about flyback diodes I am just too dumb to understand how these would work in a circuit with switching directions/poles. I cannot really show the circuit here since I don´t know the circuit of the IMS-1. So that is some sort of black box for me that outputs PWM to the motor.

Comment: I am trying to understand the circuit with my dilettante knowledge. Once the switch is toggled, the energy flows from + to - so the diode just gets ignored at return the resistor eats up the emf and the diode blocks the back flow in its specs. The switch in the circuit is the IMS-1 of course. But thats not going to work with the other direction so I need a second diode but where and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve had some experience of H-bridges that were destroyed by the back-EMF when the battery was disconnected: the classical reverse diode could not help since the current could not flow back to the (disconnected) battery. I’ve started adding some TVS diodes in parallel with the motor, and since then I haven’t had an H-bridge destroyed that way. Something like a SM15T27CA should be fine.

Comment: Yup that's a classic mistake, folks forget about the power switch.

Comment: Hmm that could have been my mistake since I switched off the PSU while the motor was turning. However how could a diode in parallel work when the H-bridge is switching directions? Wouldn´that just work for one direction? The SM15T27CA  is a zener as I can see which clamps at 37.5V, I am not sure if the IMS-1 can stand anything above 30V so I probably need to get a zener that cuts around 24V-29.9V?

Comment: @GemeloMolinero No, this is not a Zener diode, this is a TVS (Transient Voltage Suppressor) diode. Also it behaves somewhat like a Zener, a TVS diode is meant to support a huge (transient power) and it’s generally design to become a short in case of failure. The “CA” suffix means it is a bidirectional model, that behaves  somewhat like 2 Zener diodes in series.

Comment: @GemeloMolinero As for the voltage, you have to be sure that it won’t drain a significant current at the maximum “normal” voltage. According [ST’s datasheet](http://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/sm15t.pdf), the SM15T24CA may drain 1 mA at a minimum voltage of 22.8 V. This is too low. As for the SM15T27CA, its voltage won’t exceed 37.5 V at 40 A. That’s high, but your actual current won’t exceed 20 A and I’d bet the H-bridge will support the actual transient voltage.

Comment: Okay then I found false specs for that one. I really should have been awake in physics class back then so I a try to understand the math now. The motor does 27 rpm, so 162° in one second with 20Nm (initial 90Nm) -> 2.82743 radians/s -> Eb = 2.82743/ (20Nm/20A) hmm that doesn´t really make sense to me. That would lead to lower A with higher Nm. rad/s*V=A/Nm -> 2.82743rad/1s*24V*20Nm=1.4A 2.82743rad/1s*24V*90Nm=6.1A ... hmm that´s not much there must be some mistake in my maths.

Comment: @GemeloMolinero If you need some help understanding your motor’s characteristics, I think you should better make it a different question and provide the whole motor’s datasheet. Moreover, if you found my answer helpful, please consider accepting it. (I’d also suggest upvoting if you had enough reputation points.)

Comment: You are right your answer was sort of helpful. Cannot upvote though. About the motor specs http://www.smolka-berlin.de/includes/download_pdf.php?ID=338. The question is still the same though I am just trying to figure out what the worst case back EMF could be that I need to block to protect the H-bridge.The motor got a 50:1 ratio wormgear so that leads to 1350 rpm = 22,5 rps = 8100° = 141.37167 rad/s  at 1,8 Nm max at start = 611A  or 136A (0,4Nm). I don´t think that formula is right at any point :(

Comment: Sorry, but I’m afraid I can’t help you here since: 1) I am no motor expert 2) I can’t read German.

Comment: Thanks anyway I´ll at least protect the circuit from voltage peaks with some TVS.